# Android: wrong images while scrolling download with smartImageView

Tags: android, image, listview

i'm downloading images from internet using smart image view.
i placed the images inside a listview and it works fine, the problem start when i'm scrolling, the app viewing the previous images and after a while it shows the correct image, i want that it won't display anything until the correct image is ready, how can i do that?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Activity context;
    ArrayList<Row> List ; 

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<Row> List, Activity context) {
        this.List    = List;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView  == null){
            convertView  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
            holder       =  new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.name  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);               
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }
        String Name   = List.get(position).getName();
        String image  = List.get(position).getURL();
        holder.name.setText(Name);
        holder.image.setImageUrl(image);


    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder {            

    TextView name;
    SmartImageView image;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the listviews in Android are reused to help performance. The SmartImageView's `setImageUrl` method takes some time to complete, leaving it with the previous image until it finishes

You can fix this by adding the following line above `holder.image.setImageUrl(image);`

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the images on the next page are not yet loading but the ones from the first page are. The ListAdapter re-uses views internally, meaning it has a fixed amount of views which are setup with different content (via `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent`).

So when the new picture is net yet downloaded the SmartImageView is unfortunately not smart enough to replace the previous content with a placeholder :)

But you can use the following [method](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view/blob/master/src/com/loopj/android/image/SmartImageView.java#L48) instead, to not see wrong pictures:

```
public void setImageUrl(
    String url,
    final Integer fallbackResource,
    final Integer loadingResource)
```

e.g.

```
holder.image.setImageUrl(
    image,
    R.drawable.my_fallback_drawable,
    R.drawable.my_placeholder_drawable);
```

Comment: Neat, I wasn't aware of this method. OP I'd recommend going with this answer as its cleaner than mine

Comment: Yes, the SmartImageView has a bunch of overloaded methods available. Easy to miss that one you actually need :)